# Find an $f$ value with a relation with the derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a differentiable function with these conditions:
>
> 1) $f(0)=2$.
>
> 2) $f'(x)=3f(x)$.
>
> Find $f(\ln(2)).$

So what I did is I just guessed the function and got $f(x)=2e^{3x}$. It verifies all the conditions and find that $f(\ln 2)=16.$

But I'm here to search for a more rigorous solution rather than just "guessing".

Comment: Start with (2) and "separate the variables" then integrate to get $\ln(f(x))=3x+k$ and then untangle and apply (1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach 1: Use separation of variables to write

$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln(f(x)) = 3$$

and integrate from $0$ to $\ln 2$.

---

Approach 2: Since you have the *ansatz* (i.e. educated guess) $f(x) = 2e^{3x}$, justify it by considering 
$$g(x) := f(x) \cdot \frac 1 2 e^{-3x}.$$

Then recognize that $g(0) = 1$ and $g'(0) = 0$ for all $x$, so $g$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped a lot!

Comment: Don't you mean $g'(x) = 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f′(x)=3f(x)$ (which is  a [First-order linear ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients)) implies that
$$0=e^{-3x}(f′(x)-3f(x))=D(e^{-3x}f(x))\implies e^{-3x}f(x)=C\implies f(x)=Ce^{-3x}$$
for some constant $C$. Now $f(0)=2$ tells us that $C=2$ and $f$ is completely determined.